# Does VS 2010 Pro have VB 2010? Will VB 6 run in Windows 7 XP-compatibility mode?

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have Visual Basic 6 Pro sp6, and I am wondering does Visual Studio 2010 Pro
  have the Visual Basic 2010.  It seems that I encounter Visual C only when I 
  look at this online.

Another question.  Will the Visual Basic 6 IDE run in Windows 7-Win XP mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all paid editions of Visual Studio 2010 support all mainstream .NET languages (Namely C# and VB.NET). Note though that VB.NET in Visual Studio 2002 onwards is significantly different from Visual Basic 6.